# JOD Converter connection refused on the first time

Tags: pdf, converters, rtf, openoffice.org, jodconverter

I'm using JODConverter to connect to OpenOffice 4 and convert rtf documents to pdf.

It works all fine except for one strange issue, the first time when I try a conversion I get a Connection refused exception; it start to work from the second time.

I get the Exception at every first conversion after the start of the computer.

This is my test class

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.artofsolving.jodconverter.DocumentConverter;
import com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.OpenOfficeConnection;
import com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.SocketOpenOfficeConnection;
import com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.OpenOfficeDocumentConverter;

public class ConverterServiceTest 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        File inputFile = new File("C:/Prova/Esempi/TestSign.rtf");
        File outputFile = new File("C:/Prova/Esempi/TestSign.pdf");
        int openOfficePort = 8100;
        System.out.println("Provo a lanciare il processo di OpenOffice");
        String command = "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenOffice 4/program/soffice.exe\"" + 
                "-headless -accept=\"socket,host=localhost,port="
                + openOfficePort + ";urp;\" -nofirststartwizard";
        System.out.println("Comando = " + command);
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        System.out.println("OpenOffice lanciato, provo la connessione alla porta "
                                                                    + openOfficePort);
        OpenOfficeConnection connection = 
                new SocketOpenOfficeConnection(openOfficePort);
        connection.connect();   
        System.out.println("Connessione aperta! Provo la conversione");
        DocumentConverter converter = new OpenOfficeDocumentConverter(connection);
        converter.convert(inputFile, outputFile);   
        System.out.println("Conversione effettuata");
        connection.disconnect();
        p.destroy();
        System.out.println("Connessione chiusa e processo killato");
    }

}
```

This is the Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: connection failed: socket,host=localhost,port=8100,tcpNoDelay=1: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.AbstractOpenOfficeConnection.connect(AbstractOpenOfficeConnection.java:79)
    at test.converter.ConverterServiceTest.main(ConverterServiceTest.java:29)
```

Anyone knows why this happen? And how I can fix that strange problem?

Thanks in advice, sorry for my not perfect English.

Comment: I "fixed" it with adding a sleep of 3s before the connection.connect()

Answer (score 1):

What you have looks reasonable.  However instead of using sleep, it may be better to start `soffice` from a batch or script file.  Then your Java code can connect to the running instance.  See https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1014.

Another way is to use OpenOffice directly.  For example:

```
soffice.exe --headless --convert-to pdf *.rtf
```

See https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/6571/whats-the-best-way-to-batch-convert-odf-to-pdf-on-windows/.

Comment: Yes I've tried to run soffice at the startup, but then i can not open any document with OpenOffice, so I need to launch the soffice process at runtime and to close it after the conversion. (This script is a part of a software that is launched at the startup and must run the whole time the computer is on)